# The bootstrap grid does not work correctly, the row design is ignored

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap grid doesn't work correctly, the row design is ignored and doesn't work the way I want it to. I want 2 columns at 960px and up to 1140px. But for some reason it works so that up to 768px 1 column and already at 769 there are 3 columns. Why is it like that?

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-xl-3">
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/zoom.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">20.01.2021</small></p>
        <h5 class="card-title">Where does it come from?</h5>
        <p class="card-text">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </p>
        <p><a class="link-read d-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#"></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/zoom.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">20.01.2021</small></p>
        <h5 class="card-title">Where does it come from?</h5>
        <p class="card-text">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </p>
        <p><a class="link-read d-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#"></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/zoom.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">20.01.2021</small></p>
        <h5 class="card-title">Where does it come from?</h5>
        <p class="card-text">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </p>
        <p><a class="link-read d-block mt-4 mb-4" href="#"></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no bootstrap breakpoints at  960 px and 1140 px. The code seems to work as expected. Please clarify the question.

Comment: The sizes your referencing, 960px and 1140px are for the container size. Bootstrap’s standard breakpoints are <576px is extra small, ≥576px is small, ≥768px is medium, ≥992px is large, and ≥1200px is extra-large. Bootstrap rules based on @media (min-width:992px) start when the screen width is 992px wide. The scrollbar width gets added on, so the total screen width to switch from one to two columns for your code is a width of 1008px (using Firefox) and 1216 for three columns. At 769, there’s only one column displaying for me. You could add a picture of the error.

Comment: I want 2 columns on medium screens